# Responsive layout. Isotope container height and other filtering inconsistencies

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I wonder what's the deal with my container of isotope elements.
I try to implement a layout using Isotope excellent script (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html).

Here's my html

```
<nav id="citta">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" data-filters="*">All cities</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" data-filters=".rm">Rome</a>    </li> 
                    <li><a href="#" data-filters=".to">Torino</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#" data-filters=".vr">Verona</a></li> 

    </ul>
    </nav>

<div id="elenco">

    <article class="rm">
        <span><a href="/content-Details" class="detail" data-fancybox-type="iframe"><img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="caption"/></a></span>
        <h3>Content example <strong>****</strong></h3>
        <span id="localita">Rome - rm</span>
        <p>Cras sed ante. Phasellus in massa. Curabitur dolor eros, gravida et, hendrerit ac, cursus non, massa. Aliquam lorem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras eu mauris. Quisque lacus. Donec ipsum. Nullam vitae sem at nunc pharetra ultricies. Vivamus elit eros, ullamcorper a, adipiscing sit amet, porttitor ut, nibh. Maecenas adipiscing mollis massa. Nunc ut dui eget nulla venenatis aliquet. Sed luctus posuere justo. Cras vehicula varius turpis. Vivamus eros metus, tristique sit amet, molestie dignissim, malesuada et, urna.</p>
    </article>  
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's my jquery

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $container = $('#elenco')
// initialize Isotope
    $container.isotope({
        // options...
        itemSelector : 'article',
        resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
        layoutMode : 'fitRows',
        animationEngine : 'best-available',

        // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
    });

    // update columnWidth on window resize
    $(window).smartresize(function(){
        $container.isotope({
        // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
        });
    });
    $('#citta a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
        return false;
    });
    });
```

Whenever the page is loaded, all the elements flickr for a moment then they will not be viewable because of the container height… 
The page is at this address…
http://bit.ly/122qSk5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
$('window').resize(function() {
    $container.isotope( 'reloadItems' )
});
```

or

```
$('window').resize(function() {
    $container.isotope( 'reLayout' )
});
```

?

Comment: Where would you put the above code in my jquery?
Also 'window' shouldn't go without the quotes?
I tried but no chance to make it work

Comment: I think the problem is that it starts pre-filtered... try put `filter: '*'` when you instance it and in the `$('#citta a ')` remove `href="#"` and instead put `href="javascript:void(0);"`. Let me know! ;)